# Is chkdsk /R /F /X C: safe? (In repair mode command prompt)

Tags: windows, chkdsk

Is it safe/non-destructive to use `chkdsk /R /F /X C:` when you are in repair mode?

I have a little issue with a Windows computer, and I read the `chkdsk /?` manual and it seemed that using the `/X` flag might help, but I don't want files to disappear.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On average, `chkdsk` seems to do more good than harm.  However, it can be a bit unnerving when you start seeing `orphaned index deleted` lines fill up the screen. Also, I've had to run `chkdsk` more than once on more than one occasion.  Keep in mind that it's usually done in Windows repair or recovery console... NOT a live system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/X should not be used on running system volumes like C because they would attempt to dismount the very drive that the OS is running on. nothing to do with damaging the drive per se, but you could conceivably damage files that were open for write at the time you ran the command.

if you use Windows Explorer to initiate a disk scan, it should allow you to schedule the scan on the next reboot so it can occure before the system comes up. I would recommend you do that, or boot from a windows CD into Recovery mode, and run the command from there.

Comment: So if I was running in startup repair mode, with no open files, it would be OK? The command prompt in startup repair mode is running on X: drive.

Comment: TBH, I'm not quite sure if startup repair mode runs off ram or off the disk. it can't really hurt much to give it a try, but recovery mode (booted from the windows CD) is guaranteed to not use the c drive, which is why I suggest it.  What issue is it you are having that makes you think that /X is needed? if chkdsk says the volume is in use, then that means you should boot from other media to perform the repair. /x is a great option, unless you are talking about a system volume.

Comment: I have no other boot media other than the HDD. I am thinking that maybe X: drive is another *partition* than C: so would /X affect C:?

Comment: if you are running off the x: drive, then \x shouldn't be a problem, but then i wonder why it would be required. give it a try. it will either work or tell you that you can't do that.

Comment: I will try it... hope nothing blows up/disappears...

Comment: Same old error. /X makes no difference, so maybe I will boot up off a Linux rescue disk and run a disk check from there. Thanks for your time. I will accept your answer because it is a good answer.

Comment: if you are using NTFS, the linux folks generally recommend that you use MS chkdsk. Do you have a windows disk, even a slightly older one?